# TI-84 asm crash - does it wipe RAM or everything?

Tags: assembly, calculator

This is a question regarding the TI-84. I like to write programs in BASIC, and occasionally copy an asm (assembly) code. However, when I mistype the asm, it erases all of my RAM. Now, the ROM I am unsure of. Could someone test to see if the ROM is wiped when a mistyped , or tell me with 100% certainty? I would like to experiment with asm some more, but not till I am certain my programs are safe on my ROM! By the way, if you suggest that I just save all programs to a computer, I've tried that. My machine is missing a vital driver that has been mysteriously wiped off of the internet. Thanks for trying, though. Anyway, all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. ROM is "read only memory", that is, you can not write to it. Reading your question, it seems you are mistaken about what ROM is and how files are "Archived" in TIOS(the os that runs on the calculators). Files are "Archived" in flash memory, not in ROM. Although it is not possible to corrupt ROM because it is read only, in rare cases you may be able to corrupt flash (and thus your archived files). However this is very unlikely unless you intentionally try to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I intentionally induced an assembly crash on my TI-83 Plus calculator. There were no serious side effects other than the wiping of RAM.

When the assembly crash was caused, the calculator immediately hanged and did not respond to any user input nor show any change on the screen. This was remedied by removing the batteries.

I had three programs archived at the time, all three of these programs were successfully unarchived and functioned as before. I have not noticed any change in the functionality of the calculator.